# How to get items from list based on their class?

Tags: java

I have an Entity class with a List. What I'm trying to do is fetch a Component based on the class i put as a parameter, such as
`entity.GetComponent(TransformComponent.class);` But it always return null.

I'm working on a basic Component-based entity engine where Entity is a class where you attach different Components to - such as a Position Component, Texture Component etc.

This is what I've tried:

```
public <T extends Component> T GetComponent(Class<T> component) {
    for(Component c : components) {
        if(component.getClass().equals(c.getClass()))
            return (T) c;
    }

    return (T) null;
}
```

And when I try to fetch a Component with `èntity.GetComponent(TransformComponent.class).getPosition()` etc. it returns null no matter what which makes me think that it is only checking to see if it is the same instance of a class rather than class type. I've searched on this quite a bit but only find working examples in C++ which I can't really translate into Java.

I don't know if this is even possible in Java but my next method would be to have a `ComponentType` in `Component` and then just check the `List<Component>` for matching types.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: component.equals(c.getClass())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing : `component.getClass().equals(c.getClass())` which translates to: `java.lang.Class.equals(c.getClass())`. You are not getting the class of `T` but the class of `Class`.

What you would like to do is :

```
public <T extends Component> T GetComponent(Class<T> component) {
    for(Component c : components) {
        if(component.isInstance(c)) // check if c is an instance of component
            return (T) c;
    }

    return (T) null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent(Class<T> cls) {
    for (Component comp : components)
        if (cls.isInstance(comp))
            return (T)comp;

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Component.class.getClass ()` returns `Class.class`. You want `Component.class`.
2. `.equals ()` tests for equality. I believe you want any subtype to match.

So, a solution with streams would be:

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent (Class<T> clazz) {
  return components.stream ()
    .filter (clazz::isInstance)
    .map (clazz::cast)
    .findFirst ()
    .orElse (null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I 'd use a HashMap instead of the list to make sure,  to store the objects with the actual class you realy want to match against. Otherwise you may run into surprises with Interfaces and inheritance.

```
HashMap<Class<? extends Component>,Component> components = new HashMap<>();
//example, how to fill your Map:
{
   components.put(Test.class, new Test());
}

//you dont realy need this delegator. You can use get() directly.
public <T extends Component> T GetComponent(Class<T> component) {
    return components.get(component):
}
```